# Using ffmpeg to decode the video stream read from live555

Tags: android, ffmpeg, rtsp, live555

I am trying to use live555 + ffmpeg + GLES to implement my own RTSP client on Android, now I've got live555 compiled and can read RTSP via TCP, which I can see from the capture file from Wireshark. I've ever used ffmpeg to read and decode mms audio stream and know some ffmpeg development.

My problem is how to use ffmpeg to read the stream got from live555. I am not familiar with live555.

Any advices? Thanks in advance.

Bolton

Comment: I dont think you need to join ffmpeg with live555. You should create the client with live555, then it will dump it to a file (in the example) you need to check that, I dont remember but it has something to do with the Sink. That's what you should use as "output".

Comment: @webbi you're right I could use live555 to dump rtsp stream to a file, but I want to play it live. I do not know if I could use live555 to decode the stream to raw frames. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Android default player supports RTSP streaming.
You can using it stream/play video from server.

Comment: Thanks, but I've encountered some transport problems via UDP on devices like MOTO's milestone and that flashed with the MIUI rom. So I want to implement a player myself.